# Why Spring force me to use static variable?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, testng, static-members

I am still a beginner in **Spring** . I have one test class as below an run by [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) ...

```
@Service("springTest")
public class SpringTest {
  private MyService myService;

  @Autowired
  public void setMyService(MyService myService) {
    this.myService = myService;
    // below was ok , nothing error
    System.out.println(myService.getClass());
  }

  //org.testng.annotations.Test
  @Test
  public void doSomethingTest() {
    load();
    // That may cause NullPointerException
    myService.doSomething();
  }

  private void load(){
  // here codes for load spring configuration files
  }
}
```

So , I have no idea why `myService.doSomething();` produce **NullPointerException** ? Can someone give me suggestions what I need to do ? What problem may cause this error ? What am I wrong ? Now I am using as ...

```
@Service("springTest")
public class SpringTest {
  private static MyService myService;

  @Autowired
  public void setMyService(MyService myService) {
    SpringTest.myService = myService;
    System.out.println(myService.getClass());
  }
  //org.testng.annotations.Test
  @Test
  public void doSomethingTest() {
    load();
    // fine , without error
    myService.doSomething();
  }

  private void load(){
  // here codes for load spring configuration files
  }
}
```

> ***PS***: I think I don't need to show my spring configuration file , because it is really simple and I believe that will not be cause any error. So , I left it to describe. But if you want to see , I can show you. And then please assume my spring configurartion file was loaded properly and this was loaded before my **Test** classes run.
>    Thanks for reading my question.By the way, I can't also use field
>   injection and I can only use setter method injection.

Comment: Is `@Test` from jUnit? Are you trying to test `MyService`?

Comment: @geoand no , org.testng.annotations.Test;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the static initializer. Keep setter injection (I prefer it).

Use your first example, the second code is wrong - don't use it.

Make sure you tests are being run by spring (and therefore the bean is initialized correctly by spring).

The null pointer is caused by running the test method before spring has initialized the bean.

You need somethign like this

```
@RunWith (SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration (locations = "classpath:/config/applicationContext-test.xml")
public class SpringTest {...}
```

Comment: current my second code was fine for me and my first code produce error as I describe. Yes , you right I run as Test Class . I use **org.testng.annotations.Test** and run by TestNG . If so , how am I fix ? Thanks.

Comment: finally , everythings was fine as your guide sir . Thanks. But I am trying to load my spring configure file as `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
"classpath:spring-core/spring-application-context.xml");`. But it can't fix .

Comment: I really appreciate your answer , Thanks. Now I can use field injection also . I didn't think that **Test** lib may scratch my head. I had noticed that at another class files were ok but why my test class produce such errors .. But now all things were fine. :)